# SSSD with LDAP authentication, old password works

Tags: centos, ldap, sssd

My client is Centos 7 and the LDAP server is Active Directory (Windows 2008 R2).
I'm using sssd in order to authenticate to my machine with LDAP users (ad).
My problem is that I manage to connect with my **old** ldap user(s) password, and new password works as well.

When I clear the cache -

```
systemctl stop sssd
rm -rf /var/lib/sss/db/*
systemctl restart sssd
```

It works, but I don't want to delete cache any time a user changes his password.
**sssd.conf** -

```
[sssd]
services = nss, pam
domains = default

[nss]
homedir_substring = /home

[domain/default]
debug_level = 9
id_provider = ldap
auth_provider = ldap
chpass_provider = ldap
cache_credentials = False
ldap_search_base = DC=exa,DC=net
ldap_schema = AD
ldap_default_bind_dn = cn=administrator,cn=users,dc=exa,dc=net
ldap_default_authtok_type = obfuscated_password
ldap_default_authtok = AkakamaimkaA55
ldap_uri = ldaps://win.exa.net:636
use_fully_qualified_names = False
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = True
override_homedir = /home/%u
ldap_id_use_start_tls = True
ldap_tls_cacert = /etc/openldap/ca.pem
ldap_tls_reqcert = demand
```

Comment: It may be safer to clear the cache using the `sss_cache` command instead of deleting files.